# Exposing a DaemonSet service for consumption by pods on the same node

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to install a service mesh in my Kubernetes cluster, and for that I want to accomplish the following:

- The service mesh pods are run as a Daemon Set, with one replica on each node.
- The service mesh is not directly reachable from outside the cluster.
- The application pods use the service mesh pod *on the same node* as a http proxy for all requests.

In order to do so, I've added the following configuration to the container spec on the application Deployment:

```
# deployment.spec.template.spec.containers[0]
  env:
  - name: NODE_NAME
    valueFrom:
      fieldRef:
        fieldPath: spec.nodeName
  - name: HTTP_PROXY
    value: http://$(NODE_NAME):4140
```

However, I'm failing to expose the service mesh properly; I've tried with both services of `type: ClusterIP` and `type: LoadBalancer`, but with the former I fail to connect, and with the latter I expose the service mesh publicly, which I don't want to do. I've also tried to get something working with `NodePort`, but I haven't even been able to figure out a valid configuration there yet (and there seems to be some opinion that [NodePort should be avoided if possible](https://oteemo.com/2017/12/12/think-nodeport-kubernetes/)...).

How should I expose the service mesh, preferrably on ports 4140-4142 and 9990, in a way that is reachable on a specific node (the current one) from other pods?

Comment: have you tried debugging ClusterIP solution?

Comment: @MaciekSawicki: I haven't been able to figure out how to address a specific node's replica of the service using ClusterIP; the connectivity problem is simply that the expected port is not open on the node.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could put your pods in the host network space. That way you won't need any Service and your Pod will be reachable on the port you declare in the `PodSpec` on every node.

You could avoid external reachability by binding your service to 127.0.0.1 rather than 0.0.0.0

If you want to give it a try, you can run a port in the host network space by adding the following to the PodSpec of your DaemonSet:

```
hostNetwork: true
```

Please be aware that, with this solution, you'll need to use the host's IP address in order to connect to your pod.

In order to get internal DNS names resolution in your hostNetworked pods, you also need to set DNS policy like this:

```
dnsPolicy: ClusterFirstWithHostNet
```

This will ensure your pods will use the internal DNS server for name resolution.

Comment: Would this require me to put _all_ my pods in the host network space, or just those in the daemonset? This is for a service mesh, so the idea is that instead of talking directly to each-other, my application pods will address the daemonset pods _on the same node_, the daemonset pod will figure out where the traffic is supposed to go and send it to the daemonset pod _on that node_, which will then forward to the application pods there. In other words, I need connectivity between both application and daemonset pods, in both directions, and I need the daemonset pods to be addressable by node.

Comment: The hostNetwork setting is done on the daemonset, thus it will be effective only on the pods in the daemonset. So, as long as you're able to determine the current node's address in your other pods, this should work.

Comment: Ah, nice. I tried this, and I'm able to connect to the daemonset pods correctly, but they're not able to refer back to services within the cluster. The daemonset pods need to be able to make calls back into the cluster, using service names. I guess this doesn't work from the host network?

Comment: Well I don't see a reason why it shouldn't work. Are you using the service DNS name to refer to the cluster pods? Could you troubleshoot a little? Che if name resolves, for instance

Comment: The name doesn't resolve; for example, I'm trying to reach a service `namerd` in namespace `test`. Both `netcat -zv namerd 4100` and `netcat -zv namerd.test.svc.cluster.local 4100` fail on host lookup.

Comment: Ok, forgot to mention you need to set `dnsPolicy: ClusterFirstWithHostNet` (updated my answer)

Comment: I think so, thank you. There's still (at least) one link of the chain that doesn't work, though... but that's probably out of scope for this question :)

Comment: I am facing the same issue. How to expose node ip in other pods? Can't use downward api since I do not control the complete application but a python package in that python application. I can write any python code to get node ip. Can the daemon pod be resolved using `dnsPolicy: ClusterFirstWithHostNet` or is it to access other pods from daemonset pods?