# How to make daemonSet discoverable to other pods?

Tags: kubernetes

How can an application (inside a pod) reach out to daemonSet pod running with `hostNetwork:true` without using `status.hostIP` from env var?
Thought of using `dnsPolicy: ClusterFirstWithHostNet` in the daemonSet but could not resolve DNS. The caller pod does not know the daemonSet pod name or IP.

Comment: I think the [downward API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/environment-variable-expose-pod-information/) is pretty much the only way for a pod to find out its node's IP address, and without that I don't think there's any way to reach the DaemonSet per-node pod.

Answer (score 0):

According to the official Kubernetes [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/#communicating-with-daemon-pods)

> Some possible patterns for communicating with Pods in a DaemonSet are:
>
> - **Push**: Pods in the DaemonSet are configured to send updates to another
>     service, such as a stats database. They do not have clients.
> - **NodeIP and Known Port**: Pods in the DaemonSet can use a hostPort, so that 
>     the pods are reachable via the node IPs. Clients know the list of node IPs
>     somehow, and know the port by convention.
> - **DNS**: Create a headless service with the same pod selector, and then 
>     discover DaemonSets using the endpoints resource or retrieve multiple A records 
>     from DNS.
> - **Service**: Create a service with the same Pod selector, and use the
>     service to reach a daemon on a random node. (No way to reach specific
>     node.)

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50216813/exposing-a-daemonset-service-for-consumption-by-pods-on-the-same-node) thread may be also helpful.

Comment: Actually my daemonset is statsd which runs on each node and other pods need to send metrics to daemonset pod in their node. Service won't do because of the reason you mentioned. Can daemonset pods be DNS resolved from other pods? Which solution seems to fit best for this case?

Comment: "Clients know the list of node IPs somehow" - this is generally using the downward api. I cannot use that

Comment: Without using **downward api** it will be difficult to achieve... So you cannot edit `client-Pods` specification, right ? The only potential alternative solution which comes to my mind is using an additional `sidecar container` that can be injected into `client-Pod`, but it would be much more complicated solution.